# Class of dynamic array

Tags: c++

I've been working on a C++ exercise and I was unable to figure out how to do it correctly, let me explain it:

I made this class based on the 1st question of the exercise

```
class cylinder
{
private:
    float height;
    float radius;
    char * label;
public:
    cylinder(float, float, char *);
    cylinder();
    cylinder(const cylinder &);
    ~cylinder();
};
```

The 2nd question was:

**Create a new class "form3D" contain cylinders (dynamic array of cylinder)**

How to make a default constructor &  constructor with parameters?

This is what I did:

```
class forme3d
{
    cylinder * tab;
    int tabsize;
public:
    forme3d();
    forme3d(cylinder * , int);
    ~forme3d();
};

forme3d::forme3d(cylindre * c, int t)
{
    cylindre * tab = new cylindre[t];
    for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i)
    {
        tab[i] = c[i];
    }
}
```

This cause an error about "operator=" not defined for this line "tab[i] = c[i];"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: Please shoe how do you call this function and with what args.

Comment: Tried that and still didnt works, maybe I did it wrong

Comment: He means that because you defined the copy constructor (and a destructor) then you will not get an automatically generated assignment operator. You will need to manually write one.

Comment: Use `std::string`. Trust me, you'd learn to appreciate everyone who ever drove you away from raw null-terminated char arrays.

Comment: In addition to `std::string`, you may use `std::vector<cylinder>`.